# cannot declare variable ‘sasuke’ to be of abstract type ‘Character’

Tags: c++, sfml

I am learning to use the SFML library, I am following a course on youtube and I can't get it to compile this part of the program.

```
class Character: public sf::Drawable{
  
  public:
  
  sf::Sprite _sprite;
  sf::Texture _texture;
  float _velocity = 6;
  
  void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override{
    target.draw(_sprite, states);
  }
```

Instantiating the object in main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "character.h"

int main()
{   
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({1343, 715}), "SFML");

window.setFramerateLimit(60);
Character sasuke;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    sasuke.update(); 
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sasuke);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Error and a note:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:15: error: cannot declare variable ‘sasuke’ to be of abstract type ‘Character’
    9 |     Character sasuke;
      |               ^~~~~~
character.h:3:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Character’:
    3 | class Character: public sf::Drawable{
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `const` is misplaced

```
void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override{
```

It's the `draw` method that should be declared `const`, not the `states` parameter.

Comment: void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override{                            It did not work.

Comment: @MarcoBecerra Great, what is the error now?

Comment: the same error.

Comment: @MarcoBecerra Your latest code looks fine to me, see [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) for example. I guess something else is going wrong. Are you sure you are saving your changes? Are you sure you are editing the correct file?

Comment: yes, i am sure.

Comment: @MarcoBecerra Then I have no idea. AFAIK the code posted above is correct. The only explanation I can think of is that somehow you are making a mistake in how you build the program.

Comment: probably, thanks anyway.